# UITableView cell selection animation and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, uiviewanimation

I have a `UITableViewController` which allows multiple selection and it presents model of the data stored in the CoreData.

When user taps on the row we need to animate it to selected state (change layout, fade in some elements etc). The problem is that when user taps on row and makes it selected - model gets updated (because we store selected items in the model too). Because of the NSFetchedResultController aborts our fancy animations as whole table gets reloaded.

To make it more clear. Here is `configureCell` method i call in `tableView:cellForRowAtindexPath`. The reason to have `setSelected` method with `animated: false` there is to set already selected cells to a proper state when user scrolls the table.

```
func configureCell(cell: MealCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let menuItem = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MenuItem
    cell.name = menuItem.name

    // some cell initialisation

    //we have this code to draw cells selected when user scrolls our table view. We don't need animation here.
    if menuItem.isSelected {
        cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)
    } else {
        cell.setSelected(false, animated: false)
    }

    cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
}
```

All animations happen in `setSelected` method of the `MealCell` class

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)


    extraView.hidden = !selected
    let extraViewAlpha: CGFloat = selected ? 1.0 : 0.0
    self.extraViewWidthConstraint.constant = selected ? 38 : 0

    if animated {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: { completed -> Void in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.extraView.alpha = extraViewAlpha
                })
        })
    }
    else {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.extraView.alpha = extraViewAlpha
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered storing a temporary `NSDictionary` of selected cells and then only persisting the data when the user leaves the view? This should allow the flexibility you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to change your way of storing selectedItems to prevent the fetchedResultsController from notifying the delegate of the changes. a workaround is to temporary set the fetchedResultsController.delegate to nil and set it back after animation ends.